# Мне нужно чтобы при открытии модального окна контент страницы не скроллило и при клике вне зоны контента окно закрывалось)

Tags: reactjs

```js
 /// Modal.jsx
 
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import stylesOfModal from './Modal.module.scss'
import Portal from '../Portal'
import { ImCross } from 'react-icons/im'

class Modal extends Component { 
     render() {
        return (
            <>
              {this.props.isOpen && 
                  <Portal>
                    <div className={stylesOfModal.modalOverlay}>
                        <div className={stylesOfModal.modalContent} onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
                          <div className={stylesOfModal.modalHeader}>
                            <div>{this.props.header}</div>
                            <ImCross 
                                style={{cursor: "pointer"}} 
                                onClick={this.props.closeBtn}
                            />
                          </div>
                          <div className={stylesOfModal.modalBody}>
                            {this.props.children}
                          </div>
                          <div className={stylesOfModal.modalFooter}>
                            <button 
                              style={{marginRight: '15px', cursor: 'pointer'}} 
                              onClick={this.props.onCancel} invert='true'>
                                Cancel
                            </button>
                            <button 
                              style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} 
                              onClick={this.props.onSubmit}>
                                Submit
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
              </Portal>  
                  }     
              </>
        )
    }
}

export default Modal;

/// App.jsx

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from './components/Button/Button'
import Modal from './components/Modal/Modal';


class App extends Component {
    state = {
      isOpen: false,
      text: ''
    }
  
    toggleBtn = (newText) => {
      this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen, textForModal: newText})
    }

    clickedOnCross = () => {
      this.setState({ isOpen: false, textForModal: '' })
    }

    handleSubmit = () => {
      console.log('Submited!');
      this.setState({ isOpen: false, textForModal: '' });
    }
  
    handleCancel = () => {
      console.log('Canceled!');
      this.setState({ isOpen: false, textForModal: '' });
    }
    
   render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button 
            backgroundColor='rgb(0, 0, 255)'
            text='Open first modal'
            onClick={() => this.toggleBtn("First button is opened with random text")}
          />  
          <Button 
            backgroundColor='rgb(255, 234, 0)'  
            text='Open second modal'
            onClick={() => this.toggleBtn("And this is my custom text")}
          />
          <Modal
            closeBtn={this.props.clickedOnCross}
            isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
            onCancel={this.handleCancel}
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            header='Modal made with React'>
                {this.state.textForModal}
          </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App

/// Button.jsx

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styles from './Button.module.scss'

class Button extends Component {
     render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.linkContainer}>
                <a 
                  style{{backgroundColor:`${this.props.backgroundColor}`}}
                    className={styles.link}
                    onClick={this.props.onClick}> 
                        {this.props.text} 
                </a>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Button;  

/// Portal.jsx

import { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Portal extends Component {

  el = document.createElement('div');

  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.appendChild(this.el);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.removeChild(this.el);
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, this.el);
  }
}

export default Portal;
```

Comment: Чтобы контент не скролило, надо на момент пока модалка открыта у body ставить `overflow:hidden`. А чтобы модалка закрывалась при клике вне ее надо под модалкой на весь экран делать подложку на которую повесить лисенер на клик прозрачную или нет не важно. Понятия не имею как это делать в реакте, но принцип абсолютно всегда такой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В App.js

```
toggleBtn = (newText) => {
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden" // Выключаешь скролл при открытии
  this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen, textForModal: newText })
}

handleCancel = () => {
  document.body.style.overflow = "scroll" // Включаешь скролл при закрытии
  console.log("Canceled!")
  this.setState({ isOpen: false, textForModal: "" })
}
```

И на корневой `div` в `Modal.jsx` добавляешь `onClick`

```
<div className={stylesOfModal.modalOverlay} onClick={this.props.onCancel}>
```